# Query Limits with Python's Google Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-search

I'm pulling about 100,00 values from a spreadsheet and grab the first results to see if they are http or https. The scripts works fine (fine enough for my purposes) but I get a 503 error after about the 70th iteration of the loop.

Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions on how to get the amount of queries I need?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
library_list = pd.read_csv("PLS_FY2014_AE_pupld14a.csv")

zero = 0
with_https = 0 

for i in library_list['LIBNAME']:
    for url in search(library_list['LIBNAME'][zero], num = 1, start = 0, stop = 1):
        time.sleep(5)
        zero += 1
        print(zero)
        if 'https' in url:
            with_https += 1
```

Comment: possibly related info on [Google search returns a 503 error after some continuous and automated querys](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/websearch/ohIRP0uultU/zlccuRE0qoAJ) which refers to this Google Search Help answer ["Unusual traffic from your computer network"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah, my best plan around this was upping the time.sleep() to about 20 seconds, but that makes the scrape really slow.

I'm hoping someone has figured out a way to create the script that won't get blocked, or violate the ToS.

Comment: When you get the 503 error, have you checked to see if "The error page most likely shows a CAPTCHA" that you could authenticate, and allow the script to continue?

Comment: The exception is raised at random iterations, but every time I check via browser I'm able to do manual searches. I've checked a few times while the script was running, but didn't get a captcha.

Comment: hm ok, also there's a `pause` parameter in the `search` function (Ex. `
search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0)` that may or may not help with the pausing, but be careful as the documentation says [pause (float) - Lapse to wait between HTTP requests. A lapse too long will make the search slow, but a lapse too short may cause Google to block your IP. Your mileage may vary!](http://pythonhosted.org/google/google-module.html#search)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you taking the time to help. I bumped my sleep function to 20 seconds and will let it fun overnight. If that doesn't work, I'll use the built-in param.

*fingers crossed*

Comment: sounds good, report back on any progress, good luck

Comment: time.sleep(20) 503'ed after 57 queries.
built-in pause at pause=2.0 failed after 66.

Comment: Still now luck =/

I'm going to see what other engine modules are out there and see if any of those work.

Comment: I think i find the file [here](informall/informall/sources/PLS_FY2014_Data-Files_csv/PLS_FY2014_AE_pupld14a.csv), looks like that file has 9,306 entries, we split up and crowd-source the work - get a few people to each take about 2,000 entries let them run and compile everyone's results! :)

Comment: What an embarrassing typo, yeah. It's 9,400 entries, not 94,000 =/

Comment: i didn't mean that ;) I meant it seemed like a reasonable size that could be split up over a little bit of time, or even divided up by several people and put the results back together (unless you have to do all the searching by yourself :-/ )

Comment: I know you didn't =) I just noticed it myself when you mentioned the entries!

I don't have to do all the entries myself, and the crowd-sourcing idea is pretty solid.

Comment: cool, yeah you could split it up among users and merge the results. I'm willing to help if you need; but if you can get it to run while you're on vacation, all the better!  

Answer (score 6):

I'm trying to do the same thing and I was getting the 503 error after 30-50 results. I ended up forcing the search to wait a random time between 30 and 60 seconds per search. I've read of others having the same issue, and they were saying that google limits bot searches to around 50 per hour. the code I used is

```
import os, arcpy, urllib, ssl, time, datetime, random, errno
from datetime import datetime
from arcpy import env
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
try:
    from google import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")
from google import search
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(facilities, ["NAME", "Weblinks", "ADDRESSSTATECODE", "MP_TYPE"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row[1] is None:
            if row[3] != "xxxxxx":
                query = str(row[0])
                print("The query will be " + query)
                wt = random.uniform(30,60)
                print("Script will wait " + str(wt) + " seconds before the next search.")
                for j in search("recreation.gov " + query + ", " + str(row[2]), tld="co.in", num=1, stop=1, pause=wt):
                    row[1] = str(j)
                    rows.updateRow(row)
                    print(row[1])
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print("")
```

My script has been running for 7 days now non-stop with no more errors. It may be slow, but eventually it will get the job done. I'm doing about 18,000 searches with it this round.

Comment: Thank you! This confirms what I was thinking too. Good think I'm on vacation next week, I'll just let it run while I'm gone.